# Orthogonal Basis of eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure how to go about solving this question.

We are given 
$$A =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
-1&  0& -2 \\
 2& -3& -2 \\
     0 & 0& -3\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

and it has the eigenvalues -3, of multiplicity 2, and -1, of multiplicity 1.
How would I go about finding an orthogonal basis for the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue -3? The answer is a span of 2 vectors

Row reducing A-3I just gives the identity matrix, and from there I'm stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You’ve made a simple sign error. You need the null space of $A-\lambda I$, but $\lambda=-3$, so you should be looking at $A+3I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the eigenvalue is $-3$, what matters here is$$A+3\operatorname{Id}=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&-2\\2&0&-2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$It is clear that, for instance, a basis of $\ker(A+3\operatorname{Id})$ is $\bigl\{(1,0,1),(0,1,0)\bigr\}$. So, an orthogonal basis of the eigenspace corresponding to $-3$ would be$$\left\{\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},0,\frac1{\sqrt2}\right),(0,1,0)\right\}.$$

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense now!